# Create a pdf form checkbox that automatically checks other boxes when selected

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

If you look at the image below there is a checkbox on the left with the words Long Term Care. When that box is checked I would like it to automatically check the other boxes with bold lettering. I am a complete noob at this so I am not sure where to start. I think I have to go to the properties of the Long Term Care box to make these edits but that's as far as I can get on my own. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Look up onchange events, and the "checked" property

Answer (score 0):

You've not shared your code, so I'm inferring potential field names from your screenshot, but the code you need will go something like this:

```
if (this.getField("LongTermCare").value == "Yes") {
    this.getField("DailyBenefitAmount").value = "$200"
    this.getField("BenefitPeriod").value = "6Years"
    this.getField("WaitingPeriod").value = "90"
    this.getField("InflationProtection").value = "Compound"
}
```

This would require that your check boxes are grouped and named appropriately, each row in you table would need to be a separate group of check boxes. The logical place for this code would be to have it run on the mouse up of your Long Term Care check box.